# React-player shrinks Vimeo videos

Tags: react-player

I am using React player version 1.15.3 to play videos in an React web app. I am having an issue with displaying videos from Vimeo, react player seems to shrink them to mini size. I have tried the few things I can think of as well as the responsive player recommendation here https://github.com/CookPete/react-player#responsive-player but still no luck. I need to make it fill its parent container and be responsive as well.
[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozbOv.png)

## Code for react player

```
<div className='player-wrapper'>
   <ReactPlayer
     url={props.video.url}
     muted
     controls
     width='100%'
     height='100%'
     className='react-player'
    />
</div>
```

## CSS Code for react player

```
.player-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%; /* 720 / 1280 = 0.5625 */
}

.react-player {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue!

Comment: Yes, ended up being the wrapping element of the 'player-wrapper' that was causing it to shrink.

Comment: @JerehmeGayle You have wrapped the player-wrapper with some other element. Could u pls provide some info on it. bcoz still i am facing the same issue

Comment: In this particular case I think it was inside of a MUI Grid but I can not recall.

Do you have a code snippet I can look at?

I may be able to help.

Comment: @JerehmeGayle Here is the question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75901671/react-player-for-vimeo-show-the-player-to-be-small-at-first