# React-player for vimeo show the player to be small at first

Tags: reactjs, video, next.js, react-player

I have installed [Reactplayer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player) package in my Next.js application where i tried to load the vimeo video. but during the initial render the player seems to be small and then it expands like the one in the screenshot.

Initial
[image]

After render
[image]

Here is the below snippet where i have used React player to be responsive

Wrapper

```
<div className="relative w-[100%] mobile:w-[70%] pt-[56.25%] mobile:pt-[40%] bg-gold-label-pastel">
  <div>
    <ReactPlayer
      className="react-player"
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      url="https://player.vimeo.com/video/786201103"
      controls={true}/>
   </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.react-player {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in the Vimeo API mentioned here: https://github.com/CookPete/react-player/issues/810#issuecomment-604110350

In my case, I was able to resolve the issue by removing `width="100%"` and `height="100%"` from `<ReactPlayer/>` parameters and applying following CSS:

```
.react-player {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}

.react-player iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the div that surrounds the actual player like this...

```
 <div className="relative w-[100%] mobile:w-[70%] pt-[56.25%] mobile:pt-[40%] bg-gold-label-pastel">
    <ReactPlayer
      className="react-player"
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      url="https://player.vimeo.com/video/786201103"
      controls={true}
     />
 </div>
```